# How to write a shell script that shows just the content of the files with more than 8 lines from the current directory?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, files, directory

I'm new in shell scripting. How can I write a shell script that shows just the content of the files with more than 8 lines from the current directory (in Ubuntu)?

I know that I must use the command `head` and take a `for` that goes through all the files and also a counter that will increase every time when a file have more than 8 lines, but something is going wrong. When I execute the script, this doesn't produce the output it is supposed to produce.

```bash
 #!/bin/bash
 for fis in *
 do
    cat $fis
    head -8 $fis
 done

   contor=0
   while [ contor -le 100 ] 
   do 
        echo $contor
        contor=`expr $contor + 1`
   done
```

Comment: Please edit your original question to include your shellscript. Indent each line (of the shellscript) 4 spaces to render it as 'code'). This will make it easier for us to see where you should modify it.

Comment: If you want *all* the contents of any file that is longer than 8 lines, you probably need a combination of `wc` and `cat`, rather than `head`. If you want only lines beyond the 8th for each file, then that can be achieved with `tail` alone.

Comment: What is the error/output you're receiving? I am not sure this question belongs on AskUbuntu, but a sister site might be a better place to ask.

Comment: The last edit by the author of the question has removed the original question and replaced it with a new question that needs more clarity.

Comment: kindly search the forum to see if your question has an answer or post a new question, instead of editing your current question to ask a different one.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a very simple solution:

```
for f in *
do                                                                                                                                                         
    if [ $(wc -l "$f" | awk '{print $1}') -gt 8 ]; then                                    
        cat "$f" # print the file content                                              
        #echo $f # print the filename                                                
    fi                                                                               
done
```

The command `wc -l $f | awk '{print $1}'` returns the number of lines of the file and the conditional validates if it is greater than 8. If you're just going to print the content of the file, consider use the command 'more' instead of cat.

Comment: You can avoid the call to awk by redirecting like `wc -l < "$f"` (wc doesn't print the extra stuff when taking input from stdin)